# There is Something wrong with my normal map

Tags: normals

There's some weird problem with my generated normals. They're like all cutted, but my model is smooth as wet soap, I can't figure out how it happens and I cannot fix it, so please can some good soul tell me what's wrong? Here is the normal map:

[image: Sample of my Blender generated normals]

Comment: your normals are baked according to the UV map of your baking object. What does it give when you use this map on your object?

Comment: it looks exactli as the normal map all edgy, i dont know what i messed up but without this map the model looks pretty smooth.                                                              im not using a cage object to receive the data, im baking the normals of the object on itself

Comment: maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: i think i sent it, at least i uploaded it, its called Mao.blend

Comment: but wont you miss the image files? because this one is just a sample the original is an atlas

Comment: yes, i think so

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/b44ad59b2eb145b6af61fade6e0eee98 thats it, aint it? rsrsrsr

Comment: ok my bad I misunderstood your problem, I thought you were trying to bake your gun but you already have a normal map from a high-poly and you're testing it on your low-poly, so please pack your image before sharing (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend). What I've noticed though is that you have bad split normals, so maybe go into the Object Data panel > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data

Comment: thank you :) im gonna try it out